# tkinter, How to get value from 2D entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, 2d, tkinter-entry, getvalue

I need to access the value of a 2-d entry, so I use list of lists to contain all of the widgets. The code is shown below. It generates a simple 2x3 array as an experiment. My code can only get value of the first row. Can anybody please help? Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *  

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        row=[]  #list used to store a row
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(3):
                self.ent=Entry()
                row.append(self.ent)
                self.ent.grid(row=i, column=j,sticky="nsew", padx=2,pady=2)
                self.ent.insert(END, str(i+j))
            row_list.append(row)
        self.b=Button(text="Print val", command=self.getValue)
        self.b.grid(row=21, column=1)
        
    def getValue(self):
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(3):
                print(row_list[i][j].get())


row_list = []        # list of row

window=Tk()
mywin=MyWindow(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You only ever create a single row. You need to move the initialization of `row` inside the outermost loop so that a new row is created for each value of `i`

```
for i in range(2):
    row=[]  #list used to store a row
    for j in range(3):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did I miss that?